# AutoComplete: In material-ui (@mui) How to render all the properties in the json in options list and highlight the matching text in the option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

In my requirement I need to show name and email address in options list but now i can able to render only one parameter, now to render all options.

[image]

**my code:**

```
<Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    disabled={false}
    fullWidth={false}
    label={'label'}
    multiple={true}
    componentsProps={{
        paper: {
           sx: {
              border: '1px solid lightgray',
              marginLeft: 10.5,
              width: 484,
           }
        }
    }}
    options={[
      { email: 'apple@gmail.com', label: 'apple', value: 'apple' },
      { email: 'pear@gmail.com', label: 'pear', value: 'pear' },
      { email: 'orange@gmail.com', label: 'orange', value: 'orange' },
      { email: 'grape@gmail.com', label: 'grape', value: 'grape' },
      { email: 'banana@gmail.com', label: 'banana', value: 'banana' }
    ]}
    renderOption={React.useCallback((props, option, { inputValue }) => {
      return (
          <Box component='li' {...props}>
              {option.label}
          </Box>
      )
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used dangerouslySetInnerHTML used to cutomized the highlight option and to render email and label I have setted the width in the following way.

```
<Autocomplete
    options={[
      { email: 'apple@gmail.com', label: 'apple', value: 'apple' },
      { email: 'pear@gmail.com', label: 'pear', value: 'pear' },
      { email: 'orange@gmail.com', label: 'orange', value: 'orange' },
      { email: 'grape@gmail.com', label: 'grape', value: 'grape' },
      { email: 'banana@gmail.com', label: 'banana', value: 'banana' }
    ]}
    renderOption={React.useCallback((props, option, { inputValue }) => {
      function boldString(str, substr) {
          const strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, 'g')
          return str.replace(strRegExp, '<b style=color:#1e99fa !important;>' + substr + '</b>')
      }
      return (
          <Box component='li' {...props}>
              <div style={{width: '50%'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: boldString(option.label, inputValue) }}/>{option.email}
          </Box>
      )
  })}
/>
```

**output:**

[image]